# React Switch Toggle to flag elements completed and not in Todo list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, codesandbox

I am using [Switch](https://material-ui.com/components/switches/) Material UI Component to filter the between the tasks completed and not completed in my list.

See the [demo codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-sx9kv?file=/src/App.js)

I can switch the elements completed but the problem is that i can not switch back to the not completed when i toggle ( i can not reuse my entire tasks array to filter )

The method

```
  const getCompleted = (e, value) => {
    let result = [];
    result = tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed);
    setFilteredData(result);
    console.log(result);
  };
```

The component

```
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormControlLabel
      value="start"
      control={<Switch onChange={getCompleted} color="primary" />}
      label="Start"
      labelPlacement="start"
    />
  </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be filtering based on the value of the switch.

```
const getCompleted = (e, value) => {
    let result = [];
    let switchValue = e.target.checked;
    result = tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed === switchValue);
    setFilteredData(result);
    console.log(result);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle somehow the `checked` value of your `switch`

I don't know if in initial position, you need to show all values, but my answer was based on that senario (not checked then show all tasks, else show only completed)

```
  const getCompleted = (e, value) => {
    let result = [];
    result = e.target.checked
      ? tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed)
      : tasks;
    setFilteredData(result);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the toggle value in the function which is called on toggle change.

```
const getCompleted = (e, value) => {
    let result = [];
    result = value ? tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed) : tasks;
    setFilteredData(result);
  };
```

See the updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-fv9ie?file=/src/App.js)